# Power-Shell get-service commandlet - how to expand possible values for service status

Tags: powershell

If I run `get-service` it may return different statuses (0-4/Running, Stopped, Stopping, Running). Can I somehow expand a list of possible values for status by issuing PowerShell commandlet?

I tried to do this by using something like `| select $.status -Expand property`, but was not able to get this information.

I want to know how to do it that way (I know that I can find list of possible values in the documentation). I need to use these values in conditions in subsequent steps of my script, and I want to be sure that I covered all possible values returned.

Answer (score 2):

`Get-Service` calls .Net and creates objects using a constructor in the `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController` class.  You can find out what "type" the data is by piping the cmdlet to `Get-Member` like this:

```
Get-Service | Get-Member
```

The `Get-Member` command is actually enumerating the methods and properties of the object created by Get-Service as well as it's TypeName.  You can see the TypeName immediately after entering the command.

That TypeName corresponds to a .Net class which you then google (no really).  You have to drill through the msdn page a bit which requires a basic understanding of object oriented programming (I know, another google).  Eventually you should land on the [ServiceControllerStatus Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontrollerstatus(v=vs.110).aspx) page which lists all the possible value descriptions.

The values returned are actually integers, but .Net is kind enough to turn those values into something we can understand.  Hopefully if you practice this process a little, you'll be able to apply this same method to find info on other objects in powershell.